# ng-repeat is not creating list item in an unordered list

Tags: angularjs

What is the mistake in my code? `cust.name` and `cust.city` are not displaying.

Why are no list items created?

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            Name :
            <br />
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name " /> {{ name }}
            <br />

            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city' ">
                    {{ cust.name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.city | lowercase }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                    {
                        name: 'Rishabh Shrivas',
                        city: 'New Delhi'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Rishabh Bharadawaj',
                        city: 'Noida'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Rishabh Sen',
                        city: 'Gurgaon'
                    }
                ];
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ng-app` section in the HTML, even an empty one is sufficient. Also, you need to create the controller differently:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        {
            name: 'Rishabh Shrivas',
            city: 'New Delhi'
        },
        {
            name: 'Rishabh Bharadawaj',
            city: 'Noida'
        },
        {
            name: 'Rishabh Sen',
            city: 'Gurgaon'
        }
    ];
}]);
```